# perl DBIx::Class have a default filter for all searches on a table

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have a bunch of DBIx::Class Result classes created from my database schema by [dbicdump / DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader/script/dbicdump)

I need to add an `is_deleted` boolean column to one of the tables, and to filter out deleted records in **all** the existing searches and JOINs.

Unfortunately there are 30 or 40 places in the sprawling perl app which directly use the table in question, and at least the same number of places which JOIN to it via `prefetch` or `join` attributes to `search()`. Changing them all manually is possible, but very time consuming.

**Is there a way to add a default `WHERE` clause to all queries which `SELECT` from or `JOIN` to a particular table?**

I'm after some way to be able to call `resultset('MyTable')->search({},{})` and have `WHERE is_deleted = 0` added to all the queries.
Plus have the same `is_deleted = 0` filter applied when `prefetch => [qw(my_table)],` is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can subclass your resultset class and override the `search()` method to add your search criteria.

```
package MyApp::Schema::Resultset::MyTable;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'DBIx::Class::Resultset';

sub search {
  my $self = shift;

  my ($cols, $opts) = @_;

  $cols //= {};

  $cols->{is_deleted} //= 0;

  return $self->next::method($cols, $opts);
}

1;
```

**Note:**

1. We only set `is_deleted` if it's not already set - this allows us to look for rows with `is_deleted` set to 1 if we ever need to do that.
2. DBIx::Class uses [Class::C3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::C3) for method resolution, so we use `next::method()` instead of `SUPER::method()` to call the superclass method.
3. Any search options are passed through to the superclass method unchanged.

Comment: This works great for a direct search on the table in question, cheers @dave!
I'll see if I can work out a way to have the filter applied when another resultset JOINs to the table as well.

Comment: You can define a where clause on a relationship and have two rels, one with the filter and one without.

Answer (score 1):

I‘d create a virtual view and add a relationship to the view in addition to the table.